# Simulate vim splash screen

Tags: evil, vim-emulation

I've been trying evil mode in emacs. Unfortunately, it does not remind me to "Help poor children in Uganda!" when I start emacs.

Is there a simple way to simulate this? Hopefully there's just a setting for evil-mode.

**Update**

Thanks MrBones

[image]

I find it very soothing...

Comment: JFYI, evil's point is not to emulate anything else than Vim's editing model and a few convenience helpers.

Comment: Not sure why this earned a downvote - the actual question is clear enough, if a bit silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your init.el

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq initial-scratch-message ";; Message goes here")
```

The first bit hides the startup screen, so the default buffer when you open emacs will `*scratch*`. The second lines sets the default contents in the scratch buffer.

Comment: In Vim, the message disappears automatically when you insert a character. With this you'd have to clear the scratch buffer manually. :-)

Comment: And the tildes are actual characters. Oh well... X-P

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a package that fits the description: [emacs-splash](https://github.com/rougier/emacs-splash)

it is pretty self-explanatory -- it is a single elisp that puts on a simple startup screen and only after either a key is pressed or some time passes then it switches to the default about buffer or the scratch buffer. No mode-line, no toolbar etc. Very minimalistic

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please provide more explanation for your answer?  We'd like our answer posts to be as self-contained as possible.  The current post is link-only, and links can be changed at any time.

Comment: about the link -- of course links can be changed but there's not much to be done about that

Comment: Right, it's fine to include the link, but we generally discourage link-only answers due to the problem of changes and link-rot.  (Link-only comments are acceptable, but for full answers we prefer more explanation, which you gave in your edit.  Thanks!)